# How can I sort dates that are in String? (python)

Tags: python

I've only tried

```
from datetime import datetime
my_dates = ['5-Nov-18', '25-Mar-17', '1-Nov-18', '7 Mar 17']
my_dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y"))
print(my_dates)
```

But how can I make this work for date formats like

`my_dates = ['05 Nov 2018', '25 Mar 2017', '01 Nov 2018', '07 Mar 2017']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking is the specific set of dates you have provided, just change up the format in `strptime()`:

```
my_dates = ['05 Nov 2018', '25 Mar 2017', '01 Nov 2018', '07 Mar 2017']
my_dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d %b %Y"))

# Change the last %y to %Y
```

However, if you have *varying* date formats in your `list`, you could prepare a `list` of possibly anticipated string formats and define your own function to parse against each format:

```
def func(date, formats):
    for frmt in formats:
        try:
            str_date = datetime.strptime(date, frmt)
            return str_date
        except ValueError:
            continue

    # might want to consider handling a scenario when nothing is returned

my_formats = ['%d-%b-%y', '%d %b %y', '%d %b %Y']
my_dates = ['5-Nov-18', '25-Mar-17', '1-Nov-18', '7 Mar 17', '05 Nov 2018', '25 Mar 2017', '01 Nov 2018', '07 Mar 2017']
my_dates.sort(key=lambda date: func(date, my_formats))
print(my_dates)

# ['7 Mar 17', '07 Mar 2017', '25-Mar-17', '25 Mar 2017', '1-Nov-18', '01 Nov 2018', '5-Nov-18', '05 Nov 2018']
```

The caveat here is if an unanticipated date format shows up, the function will return `None` so it won't be sorted properly.  If that's a concern, you might want to add some handling at the end of the `func()` when all parsing attempts failed.  Some devs might also say to avoid `try...except...`, but I can only come up with this way.

Answer (score 2):

One inelegant solution which comes to mind is replacing all spaces with dashes as shown below:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_dates = ['5-Nov-18', '25-Mar-17', '1-Nov-18', '7 Mar 17']
my_dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date.replace(' ', '-'), "%d-%b-%y"))
print(my_dates)
```

Comment: Why not just let spaces be part of the format, at that point?

Answer (score 0):

dates can be sorted once it's a `datetime` object

```
my_dates = ['05 Nov 2018', '25 Mar 2017', '01 Nov 2018', '07 Mar 2017']
my_dates = [ dt.strptime(date, '%d %b %Y') for date in my_dates ]
print(my_dates)
# [datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 7, 0, 0)]

my_dates.sort()
print(my_dates)
# [datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 5, 0, 0)]

my_dates = [ date.strftime('%d %b %Y') for date in my_dates ]
print(my_dates)
# ['07 Mar 2017', '25 Mar 2017', '01 Nov 2018', '05 Nov 2018']
```